# DAX - Divide a column over itself with different filters to get percentages

Tags: pivot-table, dax, powerpivot

In power Pivot I have tables along the lines of:

Table 1

| Year | Month | Branch_ID | Store_ID | Article | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 1 | Sales | 100 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 2 | Sales | 200 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 2 | Operating expenses | 50 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 1 | Operating expenses | 80 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 2 | Cost of Sales | 20 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 1 | Cost of Sales | 30 |

Table 2

| Year | Month | Branch_ID | Store_ID | Article | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 1 | Sales_Ecomm | 20 |
| 2022 | 10 | 1 | 2 | Sales_Ecomm | 15 |

Table 3

```
| Article            |
|--------------------|
| Sales              |
| Operating expenses |
| Cost of Sales      |
| Sales_Ecomm        |
```

There are multiple branches and months, so these columns may not be ignored.

Table 1 and table 2 are separate. Table 3 is connected to both so that I could build a pivot table.

In the pivot table I want to have all articles re-evaluated as percentage of Sales, i.e. I am trying to get a pivot table along the lines of:

| Store ID | Sales |  | Operating expenses |  | Cost of Sales |  | Sales_Ecomm |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | Value | % of sales | Value | % of sales | Value | % of sales | Value | % of sales |
| 1 | 100 | 100.00% | 80 | 80.00% | 30 | 30.00% | 20 | 20.00% |
| 2 | 200 | 100.00% | 50 | 25.00% | 20 | 10.00% | 15 | 7.50% |

I have a measure

```
Val. := sum(table1[Value]) + sum(table2[value])
```

which seems to be working for absolute values of the articles.

However, I can't seem to come up with an appropriate DAX measure for percentages. I have tried:

```
%_of_Sales := [Val.] / calculate([Val.], filter(table3; table3[Article]="Sales"))
```

but it only counts Sales as percentage of Sales (100%), yielding #NUM! for other articles in the pivot table.

How do I define a ratio measure so that every article is evaluated against Sales?

Comment: So there is no relationship between *Table1* and *Table2*? If not, I assume that you have a separate table which comprises a unique list of *Store_ID*s and which is related to both *Table1* and *Table2*? If not, and you decide to use the *Store_ID* field from either *Table1* or *Table2* in the Pivot Table *Rows* field, you will not get correct results for your current measure *Val.*, since filtering on *Store_ID* will only occur with one of the tables, not both. For example, using *Store_ID* from *Table1* in the *Rows* field, you get 35 for *Sales_Ecomm* for both *Store_ID 1* and *Store_ID 2*.

Comment: @JosWoolley, I do have a list of unique Store IDs as well as a list of Months., both connected to Table 1 and Table 2. There is no relationship between Table 1 and Table 2, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a crucial `ALL`:

```
=
DIVIDE(
    [Val.],
    CALCULATE(
        [Val.],
        FILTER(
            ALL( table3 ),
            table3[Article] = "Sales"
        )
    )
)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
=
DIVIDE(
    [Val.],
    CALCULATE(
        [Val.],
        table3[Article] = "Sales"
    )
)
```

Comment: Your equivalence is slightly inaccurate. It is not `FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ) , … )` but `FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table'[Article] ) , … )`